# Create Node tree from list of paths

Tags: java

I have this list of paths:

```
private static final List<String> paths = Arrays.asList(
        "assets/css/custom.css",
        "assets/css/default.css",
        "assets/js/main.js",
        "assets/js/old/main-old.js",
        "fonts/poppins.woff",
        "favicon.ico",
        "index.html"
);
```

That I need to create a searchable tree, like this:

[image]

and here's what I have now:

```
public void testCreateTree() {
    Node root = new Node("ROOT", null, Node.NODE_TYPE.ROOT);
    paths.forEach(path -> {
        final Node[] currentNode = {root};
        if(!path.contains("/")) { // root files
            currentNode[0].addChild(new Node(path, currentNode[0], Node.NODE_TYPE.FILE));
        } else {
            String folders = DirectoryRegex.matchFolders(path); // e.g. matches/returns "root/"
            String fileName = DirectoryRegex.matchFile(path); // e.g. matches/returns index.html
            String[] folderArrays = folders.split("/");
            Arrays.asList(folderArrays).forEach(folder -> {
                Node node = new Node("ROOT", null, Node.NODE_TYPE.ROOT);
                node.setNodeName(folder);
                node.setNodeType(Node.NODE_TYPE.FOLDER);
                node.setParent(currentNode[0]);
                // check if child exists
                Node existingNode = currentNode[0].getChild(folder, Node.NODE_TYPE.FOLDER);
                if(existingNode == null) {
                    existingNode = node;
                    currentNode[0].addChild(node);
                }
                currentNode[0] = existingNode;
            });
            currentNode[0].addChild(new Node(fileName, currentNode[0], Node.NODE_TYPE.FILE));
        }

    });
    String print = root.printNodeJSON().toString();
    Console.log(print);
}
```

The **Node.java** class is this:

```
public class Node {
    public NODE_TYPE getNodeType() {
        return nodeType;
    }

    public void setNodeType(NODE_TYPE nodeType) {
        this.nodeType = nodeType;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        if(children == null) {
            children = new LinkedList<>();
        }
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        getChildren().add(child);
    }

    public Node getChild(String nodeName, NODE_TYPE nodeType) {
        final Node[] child = {null};
        getChildren().forEach(node -> {
            if(node.getNodeName().equals(nodeName) && node.getNodeType().equals(nodeType)) {
                child[0] = node;
            }
        });
        return child[0];
    }

    public String getNodeName() {
        return nodeName;
    }

    public void setNodeName(String nodeName) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    private Node() {}

    public Node(String nodeName, Node parent, NODE_TYPE nodeType) {
        setNodeName(nodeName);
        setNodeType(nodeType);
        setParent(parent);
    }

    public enum NODE_TYPE { FILE, FOLDER, ROOT }
    private NODE_TYPE nodeType;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;
    private String nodeName;

    public String printNode() {
        final String[] s = {"["};

        s[0] = s[0] + "Node name: " + nodeName + ",";
        if(nodeType != null) {
            s[0] = s[0] + "Node type: " + nodeType.toString()  + ",";
        }
        if(getParent() != null) {
            s[0] = s[0] + "Node Parent: [ name = " + getParent().getNodeName() + ", type = " + getParent().getNodeType() + " ]";
        }
        s[0] = s[0] + "Node children: [";
        getChildren().forEach(child -> {
            s[0] = "[" + s[0] + child.printNode() + "]";
        });
        s[0] = s[0] + "]";

        s[0] = s[0] + "]";
        return s[0];
    }

    public JSONObject printNodeJSON() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("nodeName", nodeName);
        jsonObject.put("nodeType", nodeType != null ? nodeType.toString() : null);
        jsonObject.put("parent", getParent() != null ? getParent().printNodeJSONWithoutChildren() : null);
        JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
        getChildren().forEach(child -> {
            children.put(child.printNodeJSON());
        });
        jsonObject.put("children", children);
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public JSONObject printNodeJSONWithoutChildren() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("nodeName", nodeName);
        jsonObject.put("nodeType", nodeType != null ? nodeType.toString() : null);
        jsonObject.put("parent", getParent() != null ? getParent().printNodeJSONWithoutChildren() : null);
//        JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
//        getChildren().forEach(child -> {
//            children.put(child.printNodeJSON());
//        });
//        jsonObject.put("children", children);
        return jsonObject;
    }

}
```

**The code works fine but I want to know the most efficient way to do this.**

Comment: the case here is that the `List<String> path` will contain the only absolute path of a file, and not contain "folder-only" path.  Thus, there will be no entry in the list that looks like this `assets/css/old` it will always be like `assets/css/old/old.css`

Comment: If it works fine, post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise, you gotta be a bit more concrete on what you are trying to achieve in terms of "efficiency".

Comment: Moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224192/create-node-tree-from-list-of-paths